# Shortest path in one direction "IN" or "OUT" in Neo4j

Tags: search, neo4j, shortest-path

I am interested to find the shortest path but only in one direction. For example, I have the following graph: [the graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YhBM.png)

When I consider the "INCOMING" direction then the shortest path between "A and D"should be "A-C-D". If I consider the "OUTGOING" direction the shortestpath should be "A-F-E-D"

based on the implementation I have, only "BOTH" direction can be considered:

```
   PathExpander<Object> expander =   Traversal.pathExpanderForAllTypes(Reldir);  
   PathFinder<Path> finder=GraphAlgoFactory.shortestPath(expander,maxDepth, 1);        
   Path path = finder.findSinglePath("A","D");
```

When I use for the Reldir="IN" I got this exception:

```
  Java.lang.NullPointerException at org.neo4j.kernel.Traversal.pathToString(Traversal.java)
```

Is there any way to use either "IN" or "OUT" direction in Neo4j as it is the case in OrientDB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have implemented the solution. However, I am not sure if this the best way to do:

```
Direction Reldir = Direction.valueOf(relation_direction); 
PathExpander<Object> expander = Traversal.pathExpanderForAllTypes(Reldir);  
PathFinder<Path> finder = GraphAlgoFactory.shortestPath(expander, maxDepth,1);         
Path path = finder.findSinglePath(first_node, second_node); 
PathPrinter pathPrinter = new PathPrinter("name");
Traversal.pathToString(path, pathPrinter); 

static class PathPrinter implements Traversal.PathDescriptor<Path> {
private final String nodePropertyKey;

    public PathPrinter(String nodePropertyKey) {
        this.nodePropertyKey = nodePropertyKey;
    }

    public String nodeRepresentation(Path path, Node node) 
     {
      System.out.println(node.getProperty(nodePropertyKey, "").toString()+" ");
     }
```

Any much efficient solution?

Answer (score 1):

Try INCOMING instead of IN. 
[Source](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/Direction.html)